# How to use re module to parse color names in text file?

Tags: python, python-re, txt

I need to read the file `src/rgb.txt` which contains names of colors and their numerical representations in RGB format (the file is presented below just partially). Each line contains four fields: red, green, blue, and color name, each of them is separated by some amount of whitespace (tab or space).

I try to write a function using Python's regular expressions (usage of re is mandatory!) that reads the file and should return a list of strings, so that in the returned list they have four fields separated by a single tab character (`\t`).
The first string in the returned list should be:
`'255\t250\t250\tsnow'`.

Text file:

```
255 250 250     snow
248 248 255     ghost white
248 248 255     GhostWhite
245 245 245     white smoke
245 245 245     WhiteSmoke
220 220 220     gainsboro
255 250 240     floral white
255 250 240     FloralWhite
```

My code looks as follows so far:

```
import re

def red_green_blue(filename='src/rgb.txt'):
    with open('src/rgb.txt', "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = f.read().splitlines()
            for i in range(len(line)):
                new_line = re.sub("^\t+|\t+$", "", str(line[i]), flags=re.UNICODE)
                d1 = " ".join(re.split("\t+", str(new_line), flags=re.UNICODE))
                print(d1, type(d1))
        return d1
```

I would like to know if there any other way to solve this task using other regular expressions, e.g. `findall`, `search`, etc.

I want also to know how to display `\t`, because in my case I see tabs, but not as `\t`, i.e. `169 169 169 DarkGray` instead of `169\t169\t169\tDarkGray`.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Your spec says *"return a list of strings"*, but you print them rather than return them. So tabs will appear as `\t` when you view a list of strings, that's normal.

Comment: Either iterate over each line with `for line in f:`, or else do `f.read().splitlines()` to read the entire file into one big list - but don't combine both! (I recommend the former, it's more scaleable on large files, no need for lots of storage)

Comment: You could declare `result = []`, then append your output line to it each loop (rather than printing), and finally do `return result`.

Comment: @smci: Okay, I see. What about using other regular expressions? Is there any alternative way using re.match, re.fullmatch, re.search, re.findall, re.finditer?

Comment: By the way, is `src/rgb.txt` already tab-separated to begin with, so strictly this code mightn't be changing anything?

Comment: @smci: Yes, it was, but the problem dealt with the fact that there were different amount of spaces and tabs within it, and I tried to unified this, as it was required by the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```regex
[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(.*)
```

Since you're iterating file line by line, no need to consider newlines, and only have to focus on single line.

Plus, assuming first line  `! $Xorg:` does exist in file and will skip it - as I'm newbie in linux so I don't know what that is or is a legit part of file.

```py
import re


def parse_re_gen(filename):
    regex = re.compile(r"[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(.*)")

    with open(filename) as f:  # "r" = "rt" and already default, no need to specify.
        for line in f:
            try:
                yield regex.match(line).groups()
            except AttributeError:  # first line " ! $Xorg:~~~ " falls here.
                pass


def wrapped_re():
    for record in parse_re_gen():
        # print(record)
        print(repr("\t".join(record)))

wrapped_re()
```

Generator `parse_re_gen` will return matched tuples, line by line. Your teacher/professor probably want this. Calling `return` after loop instead will only return last one line.

```
('0', '139', '139', 'DarkCyan')
('139', '0', '139', 'dark magenta')
('139', '0', '139', 'DarkMagenta')
('139', '0', '0', 'dark red')
('139', '0', '0', 'DarkRed')
```

And `wrapped_re` will iterate thru generator, joining yielded tuples with tab as a separator and print out raw tabs via use of `repr(str)`.

```
'0\t139\t139\tDarkCyan'
'139\t0\t139\tdark magenta'
'139\t0\t139\tDarkMagenta'
'139\t0\t0\tdark red'
'139\t0\t0\tDarkRed'
```

---

#### Old Alternative way

When considering this as xy problem: Why use `re` at first place?

Everything is much simpler and faster without `re` module.

```py
def parse_rgb_gen(filename):

    with open(filename) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            print(repr(output := "\t".join(line.split())))
            # do something with output
```

`timeit.timeit` result:

```
without re: 2.365
with    re: 3.116
```

part of output:

```
'139\t0\t139\tdark\tmagenta'
'139\t0\t139\tDarkMagenta'
'139\t0\t0\tdark\tred'
'139\t0\t0\tDarkRed'
'144\t238\t144\tlight\tgreen'
'144\t238\t144\tLightGreen'
```

Would be preferable to convert this to `generator` and use in `for` loop for encapsulation.

```py
def parse_rgb_gen(filename="source.txt"):

    with open(filename) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            yield "\t".join(line.split())

for item in parse_rgb_gen():
    repr(item)
```

Comment: The task itself required to use regular expressions..

Comment: While you asked *y* to solve task *x*, I'm answering *y'* - alternative way to archive same task with efficiency. This is why SO users ask ultimate goal of a question. If you have your own reasons to limit yourself to only use regex, this wouldn't be an answer if that's the case.

Comment: Either update question if use of regex is absolute mandatory. Would go offline in secs, so will check tomorrow for updated question.

Comment: FWIW, I agree the `re` would be overkill for parsing something this simple. However, I think you forgot to skip the first line of the file.

Comment: @jupiterbjy: I am sorry, but if there won't be regular expressions in my answer sample, I won't pass the tests and won't get a score for this task..

Comment: @martineau Thought that was a cat command without even looking that, will fix it, thanks.

Comment: How about now? I'll add more details about generator if you want.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: At the end, the following was assumed as a correct solution (btw, I wouldn't achieve this without help of stack overflow community!):

```
import re

def red_green_blue(filename='src/rgb.txt'):
    with open('src/rgb.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = f.read()
            regex = re.findall(r"[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(\d+)[ \t]*(.*)", line)
            #print(regex)
            string_list = list(map('\t'.join, regex))
            print(string_list)
        return string_list
```

Thank you.